# Receive data from an HTML page, after receiving the information from the server by Nodejs

Tags: node.js

There is a site that has a page with a form that by submitting the form with the POST method, an HTML page is received and this received page has a LOADING and a few seconds later the LOADING is completed and the data is received. How can I do this in nodejs and get the data?

https://tracking.post.ir/?id=221670002100060770073113

Answer (score 1):

To get you started, you'll need a few things: express, socket.io and some HTML code.

First, you'll need to install 2 essential node packages

```
npm install express socket.io --save
```

Secondly, you'll need to create a web server. Below is a very basic example:

```js
const express = require('express'); // Define express
const app = express(); // Define the web app
const server = require('http').createServer(app); // Define the HTTP server
const io = require('socket.io')(server); // Define socket.io

app.get('/my/route', function(req, res) { // Listen for an incoming request
    res.sendFile('/path/to/your/loading-page.html'); // Render your HTML loading file
    // Load some data
    io.emit('data-loaded', 'your-data'); // Emit your data to the client
});

server.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server is online'); // Allow your server to listen for incoming traffic
```

Now, you need to setup the receiving end (the client). In this example case this is the loading file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <!-- Some HTML code -->
</body>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script> <!-- Don't change this -->
<script>
    let socket = io.connect(); // Connect to the server
    socket.on('data-loaded', function() { // When the data has been loaded
        // Do something with the HTML page
    });
</script>
</html>
```

References:
- [express docs](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html)
- [socket.io docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io)

Answer (score 0):

Hei, node.js is a JavaScript framework that works in the server-side of web applications. Like PHP.
You'd need to firstly create a node project setting up a node server.
[getting started on node](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/)

to get POST parameters on node.js, you use `request.body.name`
where 'name'' stands for the name in the input field you have in the HTML form, just like the example below

```
<form action="yourAction">
    <input type="text" name='yourName'>
    <input type="submit" value='form'>
</form>
```

and in the node.js part, you type something like this

```
app.get('/yourAction', function(request, response){
    console.log(request.body.yourName)
})
```